# How to prevent unauthorized users from installing my android app?

Tags: android, password-protection, purchase-order

I just finished making an android app and i want to upload it to my website so users can download it. The problem is that i don't want them to be able to share the application, so in order to install the app they must purchase the app and get a key from me.

Is it possible? If it's not, is there any other way for making sure that only users who purchase the app can use it?

**BTW**, the app **doesn't** have any web service or **online** features.

Comment: You should make an online verification. If you give someone the app and a key, what's to keep them from sharing not only the app, but the key as well?

Comment: Try to use google play store - i think it is the best way. And even then, users can extract your apk from their phone, upload to some file-sharing provider and share it from there.

Comment: So there's no way other than an "Online verification" ?

Comment: There is no way to be 100% sure that only paying users will use your app. Even if you perform an online verification, someone can buy it and then "hack it" (i.e., disassemble, change and re-assemble it) to avoid this kind of checks. In my opinion the best choice is to distribute it through the Google Play store, because otherwise you need to implement your own pay&distribute logic on your website, which can be non-trivial

Comment: yep that's what i thought, but my employer insisted on that.So now i have to convince him  :) . I hate this part